# Grails reading properties in from files on the classpath?

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration, classpath

**Please note:** it seems I may be complicating things by using a `*.groovy` file here, because it needs to be compiled and wired correctly at runtime. **I am now more interesting in a `*.properties` based solution!**

I would like to add a `Custom.groovy` (or worst case, `custom.properties`) file to my Grails (2.3.6) app's `conf` directory, and then configure `Config.groovy` to read in that file and any properties stored inside of it.

So:

```
mygrailsapp/
    grails-app/
        conf/
            BuildConfig.groovy
            Config.groovy
            <other stuff>
            Custom.groovy or custom.properties
```

`Custom.groovy`/`custom.properties` might look like:

```
fizz = "buzz"
```

And then, inside `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
    "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy",
    Custom
]

println "The value of fizz is ${fizz}."
```

If this was working correctly, then when I run, say, `grails run-app`, I would see output like:

> The value of fizz is buzz.

Instead I see:

> The value of fizz is [:].

**What's going on here, and what do I need to do to fix this?** Ultimately, the `Custom.groovy` or `custom.properties` file can be located *anywhere* inside the Grails app (doesn't *have* to be the `conf` directory, although that would be my preference). The only thing that matters is that I can defined vars outside of `Config.groovy` and access them inside `Config.groovy` when Grails goes to build/run/test/etc. the app.

Comment: Could you try giving the full path of your file into locations..like
"file:customConfig.groovy"

Comment: Thanks @LalitAgarwal (+1) - I can give it a try but before I do, I just want to make sure I understand your question. Are you asking if I can give an **absolute file path** instead of a `classpath` URI? If so, I'd be inclined to say "*no*" because the Grails app may be running from *anywhere* inside a machine (`etc/apps/mygrailsapps`, `/home/myuser/foo/bar/mygrailsapp`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grails.config.locations` property can include `Class` objects as well as URL strings, so

```
grails.config.locations = [Custom]
```

would do what you require - `.groovy` files under `grails-app/*` get compiled when the application is built, the resulting `.class` files go into the WAR (under `WEB-INF/classes`) but not the `.groovy` files themselves.

If you want the `.groovy` *source* to end up in your WAR (so you can edit it on the production server without having to rebuild the WAR each time) then you will need to put it somewhere other than `grails-app`.  You could try putting the (`.groovy` or `.properties`) file directly into `web-app/WEB-INF/classes`, which should then allow

```
grails.config.locations=["classpath:Custom.groovy", "classpath:custom.properties"]
```

to work correctly.

---

Edit: I see the problem now - you can't refer to values defined in an external configuration file from inside the main `Config.groovy` because the process is that Grails first loads and processes `Config.groovy`, then extracts `grails.config.locations` from that, then loads each of the specified external files in turn, and *only then* does it merge the values from the different files together to produce the final `grailsApplication.config`.  If you want to check whether your externals are contributing properly to the configuration then you have to do so *oustide* `Config.groovy`, after the complete configuration has been loaded and merged together.  The simplest approach is probably to do some `log.debug` statements in `BootStrap`.

Or probably simpler still, make your generated Groovy file a proper class rather than a ConfigSlurper script, with the required properties as `static final` fields

```
class LazyBonesConfig {
  static final VERSION = "1.0"
  static final APPNAME = "example"
}
```

and then in `Config.groovy` you can refer to `LazyBonesConfig.VERSION` etc.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Roberts (+1) - I have updated my question to reflect the actual value of my `grails.config.locations` property (in my original post I was oversimplifying it). I have tried your recommendation to add `Config` as a location and I am still getting the same result. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: As a side thought, perhaps I am overcomplicating things with a .groovy file. What would a solution look like that just read in a `custom.properties` file? In actuality, I will just be storing simple key/value pairs in this file.

Comment: @Zac you need to remove the quotes round "Custom" - it needs to be a `java.lang.Class` literal, not a string giving the class name.

Comment: @Zac I missed previously that your `println` is inside Config.groovy itself - that won't work as the external configs haven't yet been merged.

Comment: Thanks again @Ian Roberts I see your edits. In that case I guess this is the root of my problem/question: is there *any* way to "inject" configs/properties into `Config.groovy`? If so how/what?

Comment: @Zac I suppose you could do the `Properties.load` yourself explicitly within `Config.groovy`.  But maybe if you could explain the higher-level use case (maybe in a separate question) we can suggest an alternative approach that means it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Robert (+1 again) - I'm definitely interested in *any* solution here. The problem at hand is that I'm trying to create templates for our in-house Grails apps using a project archetype (code generation) tool called [LazyBones](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones). Long story short: I need to be able to specify LazyBones properties in a file *outside* of `Config.groovy`, and then have `Config.groovy` load them in and use them to configure other properties. **Can you please elaborate a bit on `Properties.load`...I'm not familiar with it...* Thanks again!

Comment: @Zac does this have to be dynamic at run time or could LazyBones not just generate the Config.groovy with the property values substituted in the right places?

Comment: Thanks @Ian Roberts (+1) - Although the latter is definitely the normal/preferred way of doing things in LazyBones, for my-case-specific-too-narrow-scoped-for-stack-overflow reasons it is not an option, which is why I'm attempting this hackery.

Comment: @Zac OK, try stepping away from Grails magic for a bit - does it work if you generate a _class_ with `static final` fields?  Then you should be able to refer to those in `Config.groovy` in normal Java style.